# Apache Wink starts within Equinox and runs OK, but produces lots of warnings

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jetty, osgi, apache-wink

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin which runs Apache Wink in the container.  When deploying the plugin to an application built on Eclipse I get lots of warnings.  I know the target Eclipse is already running another Jetty container for its own purposes, not sure if it has any bearing.  Anyway, when I start up I get lots of warnings of the sort seen below.  However, Wink starts fine, and my servlets are all running as expected.  Any idea what these mean?

```
!ENTRY org.topbraid.eclipsex 1 800 2013-05-30 13:37:26.893
!MESSAGE May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet getApplication
INFO: The system is using the /conf/application.properties JAX-RS application class named in the applicationConfigLocation init-param initialization parameter.

[TopBraid Info] 2013-05-30T13:37:26-0700 - org.topbraid.eclipsex: May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet getApplication
INFO: The system is using the /conf/application.properties JAX-RS application class named in the applicationConfigLocation init-param initialization parameter.


!ENTRY org.topbraid.eclipsex 2 900 2013-05-30 13:37:26.903
!MESSAGE May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.common.internal.application.SimpleWinkApplication loadImplAppConfigFiles
WARNING: The system could not find the JAX-RS application config file /conf/application.properties.  This value is ignored.

[TopBraid Warning] 2013-05-30T13:37:26-0700 - org.topbraid.eclipsex: May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.common.internal.application.SimpleWinkApplication loadImplAppConfigFiles
WARNING: The system could not find the JAX-RS application config file /conf/application.properties.  This value is ignored.


!ENTRY org.topbraid.eclipsex 1 800 2013-05-30 13:37:26.907
!MESSAGE May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.server.internal.application.ApplicationProcessor process
INFO: The following JAX-RS application has been processed: org.apache.wink.server.internal.application.ServletWinkApplication

[TopBraid Info] 2013-05-30T13:37:26-0700 - org.topbraid.eclipsex: May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.server.internal.application.ApplicationProcessor process
INFO: The following JAX-RS application has been processed: org.apache.wink.server.internal.application.ServletWinkApplication


!ENTRY org.topbraid.eclipsex 1 800 2013-05-30 13:37:26.912
!MESSAGE May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Providers log
INFO: There are no custom JAX-RS providers defined in the application.

[TopBraid Info] 2013-05-30T13:37:26-0700 - org.topbraid.eclipsex: May 30, 2013 1:37:26 PM org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Providers log
INFO: There are no custom JAX-RS providers defined in the application.
```

EDIT:  About 5 times as many similar messages continue on.

Comment: "Lots" of warnings? I see only two... the rest are INFO messages. If you don't want to see them then how about adjusting your log settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These INFOs and even the WARNINGs are normal to see with wink. I don't see anything that you should worry about here. Wink tries several things to find providers and configuration, in most cases you don't need them.